# How to check which the fields of a form has been modified in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to figure out a way to check if there is any *built-in Form method* that would return true if the form has been modified in **Flask/WTForms**

I know that in **Django Forms**, we have that flexibility to use `form.has_changed()` method that would do exactly what i want.

I am trying to check if the form has been modified and if it is I would to do some database updates.

If anybody has any idea, please let me know about this or suggest the right approach to start with.

Comment: Doesn't `if flask.request.post:` do the job?

Comment: @azmeuk I don't think so. flask.request.post means a form was submitted, but not if / which values changed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any built-in Form methods, but here is my quirky approach how I check whether the form was changed, and which fields were changed.
I'm just storing the whole original form in the additional StringField, and then comparing it with the new form. As I don't want this field to be displayed on the page, I'm changing it's style to style="visibility:hidden;display:none" in the html file

```
@app.route("/page", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def page(tag=None):

    class Person(FlaskForm):
        name = StringField("name")
        age = StringField("name")

    class Spouses(FlaskForm):
        people = FieldList(FormField(JetsonForm), min_entries=0)
        people_orig = StringField("people_orig")
        submit = SubmitField("Submit")

    data_from_database = get_data_from_database()

    data = {'people': [], 'people_orig': json.dumps(data_from_database)}
    for person_name in data_from_database:
        data['people'].append(data_from_database[person_name])

    form = Spouses(data=data)
    people_orig_data = json.loads(form.people_orig.data)
    people_new_data = dict()

    for person in form.people:
        people_new_data[person.name.data] = {
                                                    "name": persom.name.data,
                                                     "age": peron.age.data
                                                    }

    if form.is_submitted():
        for person_name in people_new_data:
            for field in people_new_data[person_name]:
                if people_new_data[person_name][field] != people_orig_data[cam][key]:
                    #update your database
        return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template("page.html",form=form)
```